# How do you debug Clojure in NetBeans IDE?

Tags: netbeans, debugging, lisp, clojure

I have a main function but NetBeans needs a main class in order for stepping. How do you guys debug Clojure in NetBeans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the [enclojure](http://www.enclojure.org/) plugin, I am able to setup a breakpoint in the editor, and then start the debugger inside of Netbeans.  Java breakpoints within the project are hit, however, the clojure breakpoints fail with errors like:

> Not able to submit breakpoint LineBreakpoint defpackage.clj : 8,
> reason: Line number information is missing in the class file com.yourcompany.defpackage.
>
> Invalid LineBreakpoint defpackage.clj : 8

From looking at the site, it implies that debugging support may not be fully available yet.

Comment: are there other IDEs that support debugging?

Comment: I'm not really sure... I've only played briefly with Clojure.  It sounds like JSwat may work.

Comment: Any Java debugger should work with Clojure.  Some people have used JSwat successfully.

Comment: Are there any good free debuggers? And does JSwat have a good stepper?

Comment: slime should have basic support for debugging